# iPhone radio button looks weird using display flex

Tags: iphone, css, flexbox

I'm using "display: flex;" to align the sentences in my radio buttons but it looks weird using iPhone. Please see screenshot:

[image]

If I removed "display: flex;" the radio button looks fine but the text sentences are not aligned on the screenshot.

This is only happening in all iPhones not in android. Please see this example code  below (run it please in iPhone and you'll see the weird radio button sizes)

```css
.form-check label {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

label.form-check-label input {
 margin-right: 10px !important; 
}
```

```html
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <input onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-1', 2)" class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio1" number="1" aria-label="..." value="I have my own ecommerce business"> I have my own ecommerce business (or want to build one)
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <input onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-1', 2)" class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio2" number="2" aria-label="..." value="I work for an ecommerce company"> I work for an ecommerce company
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <input onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-1', 2)" class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio3" number="3" aria-label="..." value="I'm a freelancer / solo consultant doing marketing for ecommerce clients"> I'm a freelancer / solo consultant doing marketing for ecommerce clients
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <input onclick="sendEvent('#demo-modal-1', 2)" class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio4" number="4" aria-label="..." value="I run or work for a marketing agency"> I run or work for a marketing agency
    </label>
    </div>
```

What should be done?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 3):

I added a min-width for the input radio:

[image]